# Tablerow height doesn't changed?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, tablerow, android-tablelayout, layoutparams

For example I create 4 tablerows programatically and I want each tablerow height to be 1/4 size of the screen. Each tablerow height is half the screen size. I tried different ways, but tablerow height didn't change. I manage change tablerow width, but height doesn't.
Here is my code :

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

    private Context context;

    public void drawTable(){
        int i;
        TableLayout table = new TableLayout(context);

        table.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        //table.setStretchAllColumns(true);
        //table.setShrinkAllColumns(true);
        //table.setWeightSum(1.0F);
        TableRow[] rows = new TableRow[5];
        for(i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
            rows[i] = new TableRow(context);
            rows[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.images214);
            rows[i].setWeightSum((float)1.0);
            rows[i].setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 10));
            //rows[i].setScaleY(0.25F);
            table.addView(rows[i]);
        }

        LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
        l.addView(table);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        context = this;
//        TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
//        TableRow row1 = new TableRow(this);
//        TableRow row2 = new TableRow(this);
//        row1.addView(new EditText(this));
//        row2.addView(new Button(this));
//        table.addView(row1);
//        table.addView(row2);
//        //table.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
//        table.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
//        LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
//        l.addView(table);
        drawTable();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_game, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

XML:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout 
         android:id="@+id/linear" 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"  
         android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal">
        </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not using the proper `LayoutParams`, for the *table* `TableLayout`you should set `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`(as you add the table to a `LinearLayout`) and for your `TableRows` the `LayoutParams` should be `TableLayout.LayoutParams`(as they are children of `TableLayout`). Even with the above changes things will not work because the `TableLayout` is a widget that imposes constraints on its children, most notable the height will be automatically set to `WRAP_CONTENT` for `TableRows`. The only way to change this is to use `weight` like this:

```
TableLayout table = new TableLayout(context);
table.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
table.setWeightSum(1.0f);
TableRow[] rows = new TableRow[4];
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
    rows[i] = new TableRow(context);
    rows[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.images214);
    rows[i].setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 0.25f));        
    table.addView(rows[i]);
}

LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
l.addView(table);
```

But this will not work, because your `TableLayout` is set to fill the parent, parent which is a `ScrollView` which doesn't imposes dimensions on its child. I don't know what you're trying to do with that `ScrollView` there(especially as you want the table to fill the entire screen) so I don't know what to recommend you. Also, I don't know your full layout but your nesting to many layouts.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. i don't need Scrollview I just added it in testing purposes when I can't see all tablerows on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

For each table row set height:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int height = metrics.heightPixels / 4; // quarter of screen height
rows[i].setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height));
```

Comment: It doesn't help. Height of the tablerow remains half screen size. As you can see  I also tried to set height 10, but it doesn't change.